# Given $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ non singular, find a vector field $X$ with $X(f)\equiv 1$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

> Let $M^m$ be a smooth manifold and $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ a smooth, non singular function. Prove that there exists a vector field $X\in\frak{X}$$(M)$ such that $X(f)\equiv 1$.

Take a chart $(U, \phi)$ at $p\in M$ with $U$ small enough so that we can assume, with no loss in generality, that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi^{n}}\neq 0$ in $U$ (that's possible since $f$ is non singular). That way, take any $g_1, ...,g_{n-1}\in C^{\infty}(M)$ and define

$$g_n:=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi^{n}}\right)^{-1}\left(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}g_i\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi^{i}}\right)$$

which is obviously in $C^{\infty}(M)$. Now, defining $X_{U}:=\sum_{i=1}^n g_i\frac{\partial }{\partial \phi^{i}}$, we have a local smooth vector field with $X_U(f)\equiv 1$ in $U$.

I've tried to use a partition of unity to define some $X:=\sum X_{U}$, but I could not guarantee that $X(f)\equiv 1$ and I don't know how to work this out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix a Riemannian metric on $M$ and set $X = \frac{\nabla f}{||\nabla f||^2}$.

Comment: Thanks!, @Pedro! But couldn't we simply define $X:=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}\right)\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}$? Why is it necessary to talk about a Riemannian metric?

Comment: That expression will not necessarily give rise to a globally defined vector field.

Comment: To be able to define the gradient of a function in an arbitrary manifold, you need a Riemannian connection. The gradient is uniquely determined by the identity $\langle \nabla f, Y \rangle = df(Y)$.

Comment: Furthermore, the expression of $\nabla f$ in coordinates will in general NOT be $\sum \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$. There are terms depending on the metric. You may consult any Riemannian geometry book to learn about this.

Comment: I see what you mean. To tell you the truth, I didn't expect to use Riemannian geometry, since I was given this problem in an introductory course on Smooth Manifolds. Do you know some more elementary method to tackle this?

Comment: @AguirreK: You do not need to know Riemannian geometry, instead you can consider your $M$ as a submanifold of $R^N$, extend $f$ smoothly to $R^N$ (do you know how to do so?) and then use the Euclidean gradient (the one from vector calculus).

Comment: @MoisheCohen, that sounds like a good idea, but I don't know how to do it. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: @AguirreK: Do you already know the tubular neighborhood theorem for submanifolds (that small tubular neighborhoods are diffeomorphic to the normal bundle)? Otherwise, you have to take a cover of $M$ by small Euclidean balls and use the smooth partition of unity.

Comment: @MoisheCohen, I've thought a little about it and concluded this: I can find a smooth map $\tilde{f}:U\to \mathbb{R}$ on some open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ (in the topology of $\mathbb{R}^N$) such that $U\supset M$ and $\tilde{f}|_M=f$. Now I define $X:=\frac{\nabla \tilde{f}}{||\nabla \tilde{f}||}$. This may be a dumb question, but how do I know for sure that $X|_M$ is a vector field in $M$?

Comment: For that, I forgot to say, you need that $\tilde f$ is constant along fibers of the normal bundle $\nu: U\to M$ (hence, $\tilde f= f\circ \nu$). Alternatively, you have to project $\nabla f$ orthogonally to the tangent spaces of $M$ and then rescale to the unit norm.